# Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) installed but NetMsmqActivator is missing

Tags: msmq

Windows Process Activation Service is installed under features on my Windows 2008 server running IIS7.  Should i be able to see the NetMsmqActivator (Net.Msmq Listener Adapter) in the services list?  I don't see it there.  My messages are sitting in the queue unprocessed so i went to see if the NetMsmqActivator is running as its supposed to be, but i can't find it.  Any ideas?

Comment: sounds like a superuser question

Comment: I don't think any admin will know about these setting. It must be dev/architect. So not seems to be off-topic

Answer (score 2):

From the Start menu, choose Control Panel.

Select Programs, then Programs and Features, or in Classic view, select Programs and Features.

Click Turn Windows Features on or off.

Under Features Summary, click Add Features.

Expand the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0(or 3.5) node and check the Windows Communication Foundation Non-HTTP Activation feature.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I had Windows Process Activation Service enabled but not WCF Activation :-(

Comment: might be useful if you could explain the difference and what steps you took to resolve it - for others coming to this question.